# Assembly 8086 code to 8088 compatible conversion - Assembler Error

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I wrote a code long ago to get user input and print on screen. Now, i need to use this for 8088 assembler and facing difficulties. Looks to me like assembler issue, so please guide me.

```
org 100h     

.data     
var1 db 100 dup("$")     

.code   
inputString proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax 

mov si,offset var1 

l1:
mov ah,1
int 21h 

cmp al,13
je  printString 

mov [si],al
inc si
jmp l1

printString:

mov dx, offset var1
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

inputString endp
end inputString 

ret
```

Comment: Please better explain what kind of difficulties you're facing. For now both answers you got are freewheeling and one is gaining from it but the other is loosing from it!

Comment: What kind of assembler issue?  Are you getting an error message when you try to assemble this?  What is the message, and which assembler are you using?  This needs more info to make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

8086 and 8088 are binary compatible.  The only difference is that 8088 has an 8-bit memory bus instead of 16-bit, so memory access is slower.  [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088), the execution core part of the CPUs are literally identical down to transistor layout, only the bus-interface unit is different.

[The 8088 instruction prefetch queue is 4 bytes instead of 6 in 8086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437881/how-many-instructions-can-be-stored-in-instruction-queue-of-8086-microprocessor), which may actually have been an optimization to reduce wasted prefetch beyond branches with the slower bus.  See also [this retrocomputing Q&A](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/when-specifying-intel-80x86-instruction-execution-time-what-is-included-in-the) for instruction timings and perf info.

---

If you're running into trouble, the 8088 you're testing on is maybe running a different DOS version than your 8086 or something.  (Your software is using DOS `int 21h` system calls, so it only works under that obsolete OS, or a modern emulator / compatibility layer).

`COM` executables (`org 100h`) don't need to set `DS`: the program loader sets all segment registers the same before jumping to the entry point.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> org 100h     
> .data     
> var1 db 100 dup("$")     
> .code
> ```

Are you sure that the assembler that you're using knows that the DATA should follow the CODE since in a .COM program the execution always starts at the top.

Try this version:

```
    org 100h     

    mov si,offset var1 
l1:
    mov ah,1
    int 21h 
    cmp al,13
    je  printString
    mov [si],al
    inc si
    jmp l1
printString:
    mov dx, offset var1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h

var1 db 100 dup("$")
```

Comment: Well spotted.  I barely skimmed the code; didn't notice it had the data first, with no JMP over it.

Comment: Hi @Sep thanks for answer. But when i execute code, it shows error. "Comma or end of line expected"

Comment: I am using Dosbox 0.74 version to assemble and execute the code on windows 10

Comment: @JohnBravo Your mention of an error should specify for which line you got this error! Also did you get this error from Sep's example or from your original program? Futhermore DOSBox is an environment that can run more than one assembler. Please say which one you're using. There's much difference between assemblers!